# How to keep ComboBox from scrolling? C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, scroll

I have a ComboBox. It is critical that the user cannot scroll by accident and change the selected value.

How can I prevent the ComboBox from changing the value and text when the use scrolls? Thanks.

Visual Studio 2008

Comment: And which GUI toolkit are you using?

Comment: WinForms? WPF? ASP.Net? Silverlight?

Comment: Visual Studio 2008. Windows Form application. C#

Comment: How would you know the difference between 'by accident' and 'on purpose' ?  And do you really mean 'prevent scrolling' or just 'prevent selection change' ?

Comment: The ComboBox is only going to have five selections so the user won't need to scroll. I would like the user to be able to click to change the selection but not be able to click then scroll and accidentally change the selection and then move on without noticing the change.

Comment: again, how to know the difference between 'by accident' and 'on purpose'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
combobox.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(combobox_MouseWheel);

void combobox_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ((HandledMouseEventArgs)e).Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: I've used this many times to keep the "accidental scroll" from messing with a user's input.

Comment: Any idea why this event isn't displayed on the property window? (just curious). It does show up with intellisense though.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the user messing with the control, disable it. On another level however, if it's critical the user NOT use the control... maybe you should change the control.

```
ComboBox.Enabled = false;
```